# How to solve unsupported pseudo: visited error in jquery 1.9.0? in internet explorer 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, sizzle

NOTE : I AM TRYING TO ACHIEVE THIS IN INTERNET EXPLORER 7. It works fine in newer ones.
I am using jquery 1.9.0.
I am getting these errors.

```
Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: visited 
Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: hover 
Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: active
Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: link
```

I understand that a few of them are not yet implemented as mentioned in the documentation
http://blog.jquery.com/2013/01/09/jquery-1-9-rc1-and-migrate-rc1-released/

What is the alternate way to make it work?

**Update**

```
if (linkColor != "") {
            $('a:visited').css('color', linkColor);
            $('a:link').css('color', linkColor);
        }
```

Comment: Can you post your selector? I think can be related to an escaping issue

Comment: Works fine in 1.9.1, can you test this http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/s5K32/ ?

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward :link working in fiddle. try testing the :visited in the same fiddle. Its not working right ?

Comment: :visited can't work, two solution wrap your anchor and style the wrapper or use the visited plugin http://remysharp.com/2008/02/25/visited-plugin/

Comment: Better put those selectors in plain CSS files, they don't have much use in JavaScript.

Comment: Main thing here is, I am trying to achieve this in ie7. It works fine with newer versions.

Comment: Why do you need to do it in jQuery? why not plain old CSS? But to be honest, if this is your biggest issue in IE7, my advice would be to leave it. It's not exactly the most important feature on a site, and IE7 is (hopefully) not your biggest demographic. Your time would probably be better spent on other things.